# Infinite loop bug with XCB. How can I fix this?

Tags: x11, xorg, xcb

I'm programming a window manager using the XCB library. I started getting these error messages:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":5"
      after 807 requests (807 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server ":5"
      after 794 requests (785 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I expect they're from some sort of infinite loop I created, because these messages happen when I try to reparent a client window to put it into a new "frame" window, in order to give the client window titlebars and other decorations.

However, despite this, my window manager keeps running, and these errors don't show up until I close the window manager.

How would I be able to diagnose and fix a bug like this?

Comment: I am really confused about this question. What makes you think there is an infinite loop involved? The error message come from Xlib and not from XCB. Are you sure that this is from your window manager? Couldn't it be that once you close your window manager, the X11 server is also closed (depends on how you start it), and that is what produces this I/O errors from some other program that you also started?

Comment: @UliSchlachter you are correct. I do start a third party program: a terminal. And when I close that program "normally" with Ctrl+D, and then I close my window manager, I get no errors. But if I open the program and just close the wm directly, I get those error messages, and sometimes different ones. Like "BadDrawing" or "BadPixmap" or something like that. I have gotten an infinite loop before by handling events improperly, which is why I thought that.

Comment: Those BadDrawing and BadPixmap are a different question than what this question is currently about. Can you make a new question matching that case? My answer would be an introduction to the `ChangeSaveSet` request and when and why a window manager would need it.